# TTTAttributedLabel Delegate didSelectLinkWithURL not getting called

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm having problem setting up the `TTTAttributedLabel` within **my custom cell**. I have already checked many post and still didn't figured how to solve this. (I can see the URL styling at this custom label , but if i click on it nothing happen).

**CustomCell.h:**

```
@interface MyCustomCell : UITableViewCell<TTTAttributedLabelDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer;

@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) UILabel *senderLabel;

@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) UILabel *timeLabel;

@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) UILabel *dateLabel;

@property (nonatomic, strong) TTTAttributedLabel *customTextLabel;

@end
```

**CustomCell.m:**

```
@implementation MyCustomCell

- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{

    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

    if (self)
    {        
        _dateLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        _dateLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        _dateLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12.0];
        _dateLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        _dateLabel.text = @"2015-10-10";
        _dateLabel.userInteractionEnabled = false;

        _senderLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        _senderLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
        _senderLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14.0];
        _senderLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        _senderLabel.userInteractionEnabled = false;

        _timeLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        _timeLabel.userInteractionEnabled = false;
        _timeLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        _timeLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:11.0];
        _timeLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        _customTextLabel = [[TTTAttributedLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        _customTextLabel.enabledTextCheckingTypes = NSTextCheckingTypeLink;
        _customTextLabel.delegate = self;

        _customTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        _customTextLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        _customTextLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        _customTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        _customTextLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18.0];

        [self.textLabel addSubview:_customTextLabel];
        _customTextLabel.userInteractionEnabled = true;

        self.imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        self.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
        self.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    }

    return self;
}
```

Thank you for help.

Comment: If you only want touch event then you should have to use UITapGestureRecognizer on uilabel

Comment: You have not posted delegate Method which should be called on TTTAttributedLabel click. And how you creating cells is unclear.

Comment: Have you assign any text to _customTextLabel?

Comment: And you are adding _customTextLabel in self.textLabel: [self.textLabel addSubview:_customTextLabel]; is textLabel is UILabel?

Comment: - (void)attributedLabel:(TTTAttributedLabel *)label didSelectLinkWithURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    NSLog(@"Do Something");
}

Comment: I forget to mention that I can see the URL styling, the problem is while I  click on it nothing happen.

Comment: Where you added didSelectLinkWithURL method? in CustomCell.m file?

Comment: Yes, i added this to my customCell.m

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSString *text = @"Hello this is https://www.google.com";    
    _customTextLabel = [[TTTAttributedLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 300, 20)];
    _customTextLabel.enabledTextCheckingTypes = NSTextCheckingTypeLink;
    _customTextLabel.delegate = self;

    _customTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    _customTextLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    _customTextLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    _customTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    _customTextLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18.0];
    _customTextLabel.text = text;
    [self.view addSubview:_customTextLabel];
```

And set delegate method of `TTTAttributedLabel` it works fine please check:

```
- (void)attributedLabel:(TTTAttributedLabel *)label didSelectLinkWithURL:(NSURL *)url {
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it's not regular view, as you can see it's tableViewCell, I try to do what you suggested with added [self.textLabel addSubview:_customTextLabel];  but it's still doesn't work.

Comment: self.textLabel is UILabel?

Comment: Can you see the url in text?

Comment: self.textLabel is default cell label, and yes I can see the URL styling.

Comment: Have you tried by adding _customTextLabel in cell instead of textLabel?

Comment: Yes i try to do so , still nothing.